# Specific use of the word "contrast"

Tags: word-usage

Can one use the word *contrast* in the following way?

*I brought the yellow balloon into contrast by darkening its borders.*

Or does one have to adhere to *in contrast to...* or *contrasted with...*?

Comment: Sounds like you are speaking Photoshop. Perfectly acceptable as long as you have the right target audience.

Comment: Hey Stranger! Thank you for the comment. This was simply the first example that I could come up with:)